# docker cannot run in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, docker, docker-machine

[image]

> error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.26/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

Try running Visual Studio as admin. Also check if your daemon is running and ready. If you are using docker for windows, and not only the binaries, then there should be a docker icon on the task bar. Also try to give more context in your question, exactly when did this happen?

Comment: Is there a way of making this work without having to run Visual Studio as admin?

Comment: if you installed both docker and visual studio with the same user, that should not be a problem. Sometimes though, there is an issue where you needed to add the user to "docker-users" group manually that docker for win creates. I don't know how it arises though